# Есть список ссылок. Необходимо пройтись по ссылкам и скачать их

Tags: python, файлы, list, download, link

Проблема в том, что записывается только последняя ссылка в файл.
Мой код:

```
import requests
li = ["https://data.binance.vision/data/spot/daily/klines/BNBBTC/5m/BNBBTC-5m-2022-05-20.zip",
     "https://data.binance.vision/data/spot/daily/klines/BNBBTC/5m/BNBBTC-5m-2022-05-19.zip.CHECKSUM",
     "https://data.binance.vision/data/spot/daily/klines/BNBBTC/5m/BNBBTC-5m-2021-03-11.zip.CHECKSUM",
     "https://data.binance.vision/data/spot/daily/klines/BNBBTC/5m/BNBBTC-5m-2021-03-11.zip",
     "https://data.binance.vision/data/spot/daily/klines/BNBBTC/5m/BNBBTC-5m-2021-03-10.zip.CHECKSUM",
     "https://data.binance.vision/data/spot/daily/klines/BNBBTC/5m/BNBBTC-5m-2021-03-10.zip",
     "https://data.binance.vision/data/spot/daily/klines/BNBBTC/5m/BNBBTC-5m-2021-03-09.zip.CHECKSUM",
     "https://data.binance.vision/data/spot/daily/klines/BNBBTC/5m/BNBBTC-5m-2021-03-09.zip"]
for url in li:
    r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True)
    for link in r:
        i = 1
        open(f'zapis{i}.zip', 'wb').write(r.content)
        i += 1
```

Comment: i = 1 внутри цикла это оригинально

Comment: @AlexeyTen  имеет ввиду что вам необходимо вынести i = 1 из цикла, определить его, например, до строки `for url in li:` все зависит от того что это за переменная и сколько результатов вы ожидаете

Comment: Спасибо всем! Я поставил i перед добавлением в название файла: получается в выводе - zapis1.zip. И если я ставлю после увеличение - i+=1, то файл не пишется:

Comment: for url in li:
    i=1
    r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True)
    for link in r:
        i += 1
        open(f'zapis{i}.zip', 'wb').write(r.content)

Comment: Пишется только последняя ссылка:

Comment: import requests
li = ["https://data.binance.vision/data/spot/daily/klines/BNBBTC/5m/BNBBTC-5m-2022-05-20.zip",
     "https://data.binance.vision/data/spot/daily/klines/BNBBTC/5m/BNBBTC-5m-2022-05-19.zip.CHECKSUM",
     "https://data.binance.vision/data/spot/daily/klines/BNBBTC/5m/BNBBTC-5m-2021-03-11.zip.CHECKSUM",
     "https://data.binance.vision/data/spot/daily/klines/BNBBTC/5m/BNBBTC-5m-2021-03-11.zip",
    ]
for url in li:
    i=1
    r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True)
    for link in r:
        i += 1
        open(f'zapis{i}.zip', 'wb').write(r.content)

Comment: Как поменять код?

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests

li = ["https://data.binance.vision/data/spot/daily/klines/BNBBTC/5m/BNBBTC-5m-2022-05-20.zip",
      "https://data.binance.vision/data/spot/daily/klines/BNBBTC/5m/BNBBTC-5m-2022-05-19.zip.CHECKSUM",
      "https://data.binance.vision/data/spot/daily/klines/BNBBTC/5m/BNBBTC-5m-2021-03-11.zip.CHECKSUM",
      "https://data.binance.vision/data/spot/daily/klines/BNBBTC/5m/BNBBTC-5m-2021-03-11.zip",
      "https://data.binance.vision/data/spot/daily/klines/BNBBTC/5m/BNBBTC-5m-2021-03-10.zip.CHECKSUM",
      "https://data.binance.vision/data/spot/daily/klines/BNBBTC/5m/BNBBTC-5m-2021-03-10.zip",
      "https://data.binance.vision/data/spot/daily/klines/BNBBTC/5m/BNBBTC-5m-2021-03-09.zip.CHECKSUM",
      "https://data.binance.vision/data/spot/daily/klines/BNBBTC/5m/BNBBTC-5m-2021-03-09.zip"]
for url in li:
    name = url.split('/')[-1]
    r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True)
    print(f'zip\\{name}')
    with open(f'zip\\{name}', 'wb') as file:
        file.write(r.content)
print('ГОТОВО')
```

Answer (score 0):

Ответ:

```
import requests
li = ["https://data.binance.vision/data/spot/daily/klines/BNBBTC/5m/BNBBTC-5m-2022-05-20.zip",
          "https://data.binance.vision/data/spot/daily/klines/BNBBTC/5m/BNBBTC-5m-2021-03-11.zip",
          "https://data.binance.vision/data/spot/daily/klines/BNBBTC/5m/BNBBTC-5m-2021-03-10.zip",
          "https://data.binance.vision/data/spot/daily/klines/BNBBTC/5m/BNBBTC-5m-2021-03-09.zip"]
def download_test(li):
    i = 0
    for u in li:
        i+=1
        response = requests.get(u)
        with open(f'data{i}.zip', 'wb') as file:
            file.write(response.content)
        print(f'Im successfully downloaded "data{i}.zip"! ')
def main():
    download_test(li)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).